# Problem loading background image from external css (django)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm having trouble loading an image via external CSS on Django. It works fine using inline CSS but I want to understand why it doesn't work using external one. Any help would be appreciated:

My tree:

```
├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   └───website
│       ├───css
│       ├───img
│       └───js
├───templates
│   └───website
└───__pycache__
```

CSS:

```
.body {
  background: url('/static/website/img/Racoon.jpg');
}
```

HTML:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'website/css/main.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Russo+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
{% block title %}
<title> Home </title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1> Home </h1>
<p> Homepage of the website </p>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

P.S I'm using localhost and image does load via URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/website/img/Racoon.jpg

Comment: Django static files load only in html file.Not work in other files like external css file. It's django templating rule. Replace with .body {
  background: url('../img/Racoon.jpg');
}

Comment: thanks, didn't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
.body {
  background: url('/static/website/img/Racoon.jpg');
}
```

with

```
.body {
  background: url('../img/Racoon.jpg');
}
```

`../`means parent directory. you first go back to your `static/website` folder, and go to `img` folder and find your image.

**If it is still not working, clear browser history and try again.**

Answer (score -1):

just type command python manage.py collectstatic
this is same with me after correct usage of above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).